# Correct .htaccess to redirect all https:// pages to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all non-www pages to https://, but only the home page does so as expected. That is, http://kraftgiftbox.com will redirect to https://www.kraftgiftbox.com/ as I expect, that's ok!
But none of the sub-level page will, like https://kraftgiftbox.com/odd-shaped-boxes.html, it won't redirect to the www version.
I had a .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://kraftgiftbox.com/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kraftgiftbox\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.kraftgiftbox\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please help me correct the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The last line of rules caused that because you only capture root request by this `RewriteRule ^/?$` , to achieve what you want try this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml 
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kraftgiftbox\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kraftgiftbox.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Rules above will do both , forcing `https` and `www` as well.

**Note** clear browser cache then test.